# Microsoft.Web.Configuration.AppHostFileProvider not found after configured Remote IIS Administration for Microsoft Azure Web App

Tags: azure, iis, azure-web-app-service

A few months earlier I could successfully configure Remote IIS Administration for my Azure Web App. After changed the office, I found that after configured the Remote IIS Administration on my new computer, I encountered the following error when I try to click my website:

[image]

I use Internet Information Services (Version 10.0.16299.15) and installed [IIS Manager for Remote Administration 1.2](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=41177). And I followed [Configure Remote IIS Administration for Microsoft Azure App Service](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/benjaminperkins/2014/08/05/configure-remote-iis-administration-for-microsoft-azure-web-sites/) to configure Remote IIS Administration.

I also checked that web app uses Microsoft-IIS/10.0 for now. As [IIS Manager for Remote Administration 1.2](https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/iis-manager) noted:

> Works With: IIS 7, IIS 7.5, IIS 8, IIS 8.5

Does IIS Manager for Remote Administration not work under IIS 10.0? My previous working computer is Windows 10 and I do not remember the version of IIS, maybe IIS 8.5 or IIS 10.0.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try to manage a local Windows Server 2016 server so that the necessary assemblies can be downloaded and installed. Then you should be able to manage Azure side resources.

Answer (score 1):

Late answer but for anyone else finding this: 
IIS Manager support has been removed from Azure Web Apps.

Reference: https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169385-web-apps/suggestions/34379356-use-iis-manager-to-administrate-web-app

> declined  ·  AdminAzure App Service team (Product Owner, Microsoft
>   Azure) responded  ·  February 28, 2019
>
> Thank you for taking the time to submit and vote for this feature
>   request. The errors were thrown because we no longer support the IIS
>   manager. Going forward, please edit the web.config manually.
>
> Thanks, Jason

Comment: also the reference link you posted cannot be found...