# Connecting to an Azure App Service via IIS Manager (inetmgr)

Tags: azure, iis, azure-web-app-service, kudu

Is it possible to remote-connect to an Azure App Service running on Windows with my IIS Manager?

This seems to have been possible according to [this](https://edi.wang/post/2015/7/23/how-to-manage-azure-app-service-in-iis-manager-inetmgr) blog post by clicking in IIS Manager File -> Connect to a site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I refer to the steps mentioned in the [link](https://edi.wang/post/2015/7/23/how-to-manage-azure-app-service-in-iis-manager-inetmgr) shared by you and in the last step I got an error below.

[image]

I did some research on it and it looks like managing the App Service from IIS is not supported anymore. I have not got any official link but the below links might give you some information on it.

1. [Microsoft.Web.Configuration.AppHostFileProvider not found after configured Remote IIS Administration for Microsoft Azure Web App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50245059/microsoft-web-configuration-apphostfileprovider-not-found-after-configured-remot)
2. [Can no longer manage any Web Apps with IIS Remote Manager - Could not load file or assembly - AppHostFileProvider](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/SECURITY/en-US/e5ef578b-8a83-4e46-84dd-3113488b579b/can-no-longer-manage-any-web-apps-with-iis-remote-manager-could-not-load-file-or-assembly-?forum=windowsazurewebsitespreview)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure for what purpose why you want to. My thoughts is you shouldn't be doing that as it defeat the purpose of PaaS services. Cannot access the iis layer in app service however you can still configure in web.config of your web app.